# Document Information Panel with Word Web App

Tags: word, document-info-panel, office-web-apps

When a SharePoint 2010 Document is opened inside Word Client, it shows the properties of that document in a Document Information Panel. How does this work with Word Web App?

Answer (score 3):

You do not have access to the DIP in Office Web Apps. Since you're using the web UI already it's easy to go the the item in the library and change it's properties there. If you need more advanced DIP's (for instance built with InfoPath) then you need to modify the edit, new and view forms of the page to get the "same" experience as in the full fledged Office client.

Comment: Yes, it does not seem to be available. But the issue is - it does not even load a document (if a document is mapped to a Content Type with 5 or 10 fields) and Edit In Browser is selected, the Word Web App says "Cannot load the document". But on a different document library like "Shared Documents" with No Content Type association, the Edit In Browser, does seem to work.